# How can I show the output of <%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %> or <% Eval('column name') %> on a stringbuilder?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

How can I show the output of <%# Container.ItemIndex  + 1  %> or <% Eval('column name') %> on a stringbuilder? Because I have to export the output of the DataList with the design from the Item Template of the DataList...

**This is from the Page.aspx**

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.ItemIndex  + 1  %>'></asp:Label><br />
 <p class="description"><%# Eval("column name")%></p>
```

**and this is on the Page.aspx.cs**

```
 protected string ExportDatatableToHtml(DataTable dt)
    {
        StringBuilder strHTMLBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        strHTMLBuilder.Append("<html >");
        strHTMLBuilder.Append("<head>");
        strHTMLBuilder.Append("</head>");
        strHTMLBuilder.Append("<body>");
        strHTMLBuilder.Append("<bgcolor='white' >");

        strHTMLBuilder.Append("<tr >");
        foreach (DataColumn myColumn in dt.Columns)
        {
            strHTMLBuilder.Append("<td >");
            strHTMLBuilder.Append(myColumn.ColumnName);
            strHTMLBuilder.Append("</td>");

        }
        strHTMLBuilder.Append("</tr>");


        foreach (DataRow myRow in dt.Rows)
        {

            strHTMLBuilder.Append("<tr >");
            foreach (DataColumn myColumn in dt.Columns)
            {
                strHTMLBuilder.Append("<td >");
                strHTMLBuilder.Append(myRow[myColumn.ColumnName].ToString());
                strHTMLBuilder.Append("</td>");

            }
            strHTMLBuilder.Append("</tr>");
        }

        //Close tags.  
        strHTMLBuilder.Append("</table>");
        strHTMLBuilder.Append("</body>");
        strHTMLBuilder.Append("</html>");

        string Htmltext = strHTMLBuilder.ToString();

        return Htmltext;
    }
```

I wonder if this is really possible... if yes, can you teach me how to do it?

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do here? You are already doing `myColumn.ColumnName` in the code? Where exactly you want Container.ItemIndex in the code?

Comment: I made an alternative on Container.ItemIndex, but using foreach   foreach (DataRow myRow in dt.Rows)
            {
                i++;
                strHTMLBuilder.Append(i);
}

My only problem now is to get the Eval data...

Comment: for example, I want to get the <% Eval('studentid') %> to append to string, is that possible?

Comment: ` Eval('studentid') ` is nothing but value of `studentid` column in current row which is binding to the control. In your code you can directly get that value from the datatable `dt`. `myRow[myColumn.ColumnName].ToString()` should be doing that job. It is really not clear what you are asking based on the code you shared.

Comment: myRow[myColumn.ColumnName].ToString() then how do I specifically call for a certain column name? 

I am actually exporting the output of my DataList using asp.net to HTML File

Comment: You need to pass that certain column name to `myRow[<<certaincolumnname>>].ToString()`. It would be `myRow["StudentId"].ToString()` in your case. What output you are getting from the current code?

Comment: Thanks alot Chetan, I got it now because of the one you said ----> myRow["StudentId"].ToString()

Comment: Chetan, is it possible to append 'source code'?

Comment: What do you mean by append 'Source Code'? I didn't get it

Comment: never mind, I just hard coded all the source code of the output of datalist with div, design etc... Thank you again chetan

Answer (score 1):

I got the idea when Chetan commented on this question about

```
<%# Eval("column name")%>
```

in order for me to append this, I used

```
  foreach (DataRow myRow in dt.Rows)
            {
    string studentid= myRow["studentid"].ToString();
    strHTMLBuilder.Append(studentid);
            }
```

then in exchange for Container.ItemIndex + 1 on asp.net, to export to html I used this

```
   int i = 0;
   foreach (DataRow myRow in dt.Rows)
                {
        i++;
        strHTMLBuilder.Append(i);
                }
```